# Best relation between one and three other tables

Tags: sql, database, data-modeling

I'm extending a model for a CRM application.

In the existing model we have these tables:

- Person p
- Company c
- CompanyPerson cp (n:m)

We want to create a new table called:

- Relation

That can be a:

- Person
- Company
- Person working at a Company

What is the best way to define this table?

1. Make 3 nullable FK's in `Relation` and one of them needs to be not null (in code)
2. Make 2 nullable FK's in `Relation` to p and c and one or both need to be not null (in code)
3. Make 3 new n:m tables between `Relation` and these tables (p, c, cp)

Thanks,
Evert-Jan

Comment: What is the new table supposed to be good for? It looks strange that a "person" is a "relation". On first glimpse, it doesn't seem a good model for anything.

Comment: @Thorsten: It is for a simulation program. For example, a letter must be attached to a relation. And you have business and private customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So relation is more or less a contact, which is either a private relation (a contact to a person) or to a company or to a particular person in a company.

So a relation should have two optional (i.e. nullable) fields: for a person and for a company.

- Person (*id_person*, firstname, surname, ...)
- Company (*id_company*, name, ...)
- CompanyPerson (*id_person*, *id_company*, job, salary, ...)
- Relation (*id_relation*, id_person, id_company, letter, ...)

You'd have foreign key constraints to Person, Company and CompanyPerson, so whenever id_person is filled it must be in table Person; whenever id_company is filled it must be in table Company; whenever both are filled they must be in table CompanyPerson.

Moreover you'd add a check constraint to ensure that at least one of the two fields is filled for each Relation record.

Comment: Ok, that matches my option 2, which I also think is the best. But how can I 
"add a check constraint to ensure that at least one of the two fields is filled for each Relation record." ?

Comment: That depends on the dbms. In Oracle that would be `CHECK(id_person is not null or id_company is not null)` for instance. MySQL, as another example, doesn't know check constraints. Here you would write before-insert/update triggers that throw an error when both fields are null.

Comment: This solution uses MS Sql

Comment: Since the Relation table is "more or less a Contact" and in my head a Person is also "more or less a Contact" then maybe you should be storing Relation data in the Contact table?  You would then need to rework your bridge table to represent both Person to Person and Person to Company relationships.

Comment: @Evert-Jan Modderkolk: I suppose "MS Sql" means SQL Server, not MS Access? SQL Server knows check constraints like Oracle does.

Comment: Indeed SQL Server. I used your solution and it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another idea of a implementation can be what people call a `polymorphic association`. Your `Relation` table should contain 2 fields, both `NOT NULL` like this:

```
Relation
  - entity varchar(10) NOT NULL
  - entity_id integer NOT NULL
```

When it is a person, the `entity` field should contain the string `Person` and the `entity_id` should contain the foreign key to the `Person` table.
When it is a company, the `entity` field should contain the string `Company` and the `entity_id` should contain the foreign key to the `Company` table.

Then you can abstract this on your application code.

Comment: How do you ensure database integrity?